# Filter elements from list of dictionaries in ansible that match a condition

Tags: ansible

Below is a contrived example of my data. I want to extract the names of all customers when any of the dicts in the list `mylst.env` has a key with name `n1`
I imagine this can be done with a nested loop, but cannot figure out how.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - mylst:
        - apiVersion: v1
          name: customer1
          metaData:
              cycles: 10
              ships: 12
          env:
            - name: n1
              value: v1
            - name: n2
              value: v2
        - apiVersion: v1
          name: customer2
          metaData:
              cycles: 10
              ships: 12
          env:
            - name: n1
              value: v1
            - name: n3
              value: v3
        - apiVersion: v1
          name: customer3
          metaData:
              cycles: 10
              ships: 12
          env:
            - name: n3
              value: v1
            - name: n4
              value: v4
  tasks:
  - set_fact: 
       cust_lst: "{{ cust_lst|default([]) + [item.name] }}"
    with_items: "{{ mylst }}"
    # loop through item.env and look for elements where elem.name == n1
    when: item.env | length > 0

  - debug: var=cust_lst
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the `map` filter on the `item.env` list to get a list of names each element in the `mylst` contains. then if the keyword "n1" is in that list, add to the `final_var`. please see below

### PLAYBOOK:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    mylst:
    - apiVersion: v1
      name: customer1
      metaData:
          cycles: 10
          ships: 12
      env:
        - name: n1
          value: v1
        - name: n2
          value: v2
    - apiVersion: v1
      name: customer2
      metaData:
          cycles: 10
          ships: 12
      env:
        - name: n1
          value: v1
        - name: n3
          value: v3
    - apiVersion: v1
      name: customer3
      metaData:
          cycles: 10
          ships: 12
      env:
        - name: n3
          value: v1
        - name: n4
          value: v4
    - apiVersion: v1
      name: customer4
      metaData:
          cycles: 10
          ships: 12
      env:
        - name2: n3
          value: v1
        - name2: n4
          value: v4

  tasks:

  - name: prepare var
    set_fact:
      final_var: "{{ final_var | default([]) + [item.name] }}"
    when: '"n1" in {{ item.env | selectattr("name", "defined") | map(attribute="name") | list }}'
    with_items:
    - "{{ mylst }}"

  - name: print var
    debug:
      var: final_var
```

you will notice that i added a 4th element in the `mylst` that contains no attributes with key = "name". these will be filtered out by the `selectattr("name", "defined"` filter, before passed to the map filter.

### OUTPUT:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [prepare var] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: "n1" in {{ item.env | selectattr("name", "defined") | map(attribute="name") | list }}

ok: [localhost] => (item={'apiVersion': 'v1', 'name': 'customer1', 'metaData': {'cycles': 10, 'ships': 12}, 'env': [{'name': 'n1', 'value': 'v1'}, {'name': 'n2', 'value': 'v2'}]})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'apiVersion': 'v1', 'name': 'customer2', 'metaData': {'cycles': 10, 'ships': 12}, 'env': [{'name': 'n1', 'value': 'v1'}, {'name': 'n3', 'value': 'v3'}]})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'apiVersion': 'v1', 'name': 'customer3', 'metaData': {'cycles': 10, 'ships': 12}, 'env': [{'name': 'n3', 'value': 'v1'}, {'name': 'n4', 'value': 'v4'}]}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'apiVersion': 'v1', 'name': 'customer4', 'metaData': {'cycles': 10, 'ships': 12}, 'env': [{'name2': 'n3', 'value': 'v1'}, {'name2': 'n4', 'value': 'v4'}]}) 

TASK [print var] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final_var": [
        "customer1",
        "customer2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

hope these help.

### for ansible 2.7.5 error (as described in comments below)

this task was found to be circumventing the 2.7.5 error:

```
  - name: prepare var
    set_fact:
      final_var: "{{ final_var | default([]) + [item.name] }}"
    when: "'n1' in item.env | selectattr('name', 'defined') | map(attribute='name') | list"
    with_items:
    - "{{ mylst }}"
```

Comment: I am using ansible 2.7.5 and see the following error: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '\"n1\" in {{ item.env | selectattr(\"name\", \"defined\") | map(attribute=\"name\") | list }}' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'string'. String: {% if \"n1\" in [u'n1', u'n2'] %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/so.yml': line 48, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: prepare var\n    ^ here\n"}

Comment: You are right. I am using 2.9.1, but downgraded to 2.7.5 and i got the same error as you did. if you upgrade to 2.9.1 it will work fine, cant tell why its not working in 2.7.5, too many versions between the two, to go over the release notes/bugfixes of each one :(

Comment: Well, please see added task in the end of my answer, it did the trick in 2.7.5!

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again for finding a solution for 2.7.5

Answer (score 10):

The `json_query` filter is a great tool for these kinds of tasks. It takes a little while to wrap your head around, but give this a go:

```
  - set_fact:
      cust_lst: "{{ mylst | json_query(query) }}"
    vars:
      query: "[?env[?name=='n1']].name"
```

You can find out more at the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) and this shamelessly plugged [blog post](https://parko.id.au/2018/08/16/complex-data-structures-and-the-ansible-json_query-filter/)

Comment: Thanks for this neat solution. I did read through your block while researching json_query but was unable to construct a query that would suit my needs.

Comment: Might be time for an update :)  I've learnt a fair bit about it myself since then

Comment: The official documentation of the json_query filter has been moved to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide.html

Comment: Updated - thanks @AdanCortes